# jsonconverter Web api datetime property getting 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api controller method that is accepting a composite object where one of the properties is a DateTime. The client wants us to expose the date in yyyyMMdd format. I am using 
the following to the property

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateConverter))]
public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

public class CustomDateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
    }
}
```

And there is another property, whether the client will send only time i.e hhmmss format
When i send a date in fiddler to test this method, i am getting the datevalue in the model as 01/01/0001 00:00:000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works for console application, see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BHdJOm)

For Web API you may want to register your `CustomDateConverter` formatter in global.asax

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomDateConverter());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters[0] = new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings);
```

Comment: and override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, i have registered in webapiconfig

Comment: settings.Converters.Add(new CustomDateConverter());

Comment: var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            settings.Converters.Add(new CustomDateConverter());

Comment: The client transactionDate in yyyyMMdd format and transcationTime in hhmmss format. Currently the converter works for json response but how to deserialize the date when the client send to my web api method. Please help.